# Suddenly not able to access resources on VPN network in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm using openvpn, and had imported my client.ovpn file to Network Manager via the GUI.

Up until yesterday I was able to access resources on my company's VPN network without any issues. At first, I was unable to access any resources at all when logged into the VPN. Our sysadmin changed the VPN settings so that client Internet traffic isn't routed through the VPN. This fixed my internet issues, but didn't resolve the underlying issue, which is that I can't access resources inside the VPN.

Nslookup-ing some of the target machines while on the VPN returns valid responses, but a traceroute to the same machine gives me !H (unreachable) hops.

At this point, I'm unsure how to proceed. Another user was able to use the VPN just fine using Debian, and users on Macs haven't had any problems, so I'm pretty sure the issue is related to my local machine.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling ubuntu, and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem a couple months ago.  My vpn would not work.  I deleted all vpn config files and then downloaded them again, had to reboot machine two or three times till everything worked again.